# Android VideoView Error: 1,-19

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player, android-videoview

Can anyone tell me how to use videoview to play mp4 url. I have written the code which is giving me error in my logcat as:

```
08-05 04:37:35.978: D/MediaPlayer(1693): getMetadata
08-05 04:37:37.918: E/MediaPlayer(1693): error (1, -19)
08-05 04:37:37.928: E/MediaPlayer(1693): Error (1,-19)
08-05 04:37:37.928: D/VideoView(1693): Error: 1,-19
```

I am using the videoview java code as:

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_play);


        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview_video);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        System.out.println(mediaController);
        Uri video = Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.100/Android/jum.mp4");
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        System.out.println("View:"+videoView);
        videoView.start();

    }
}
```

I have made the video as H 264 compressed format but also i am not able to watch and listen the video 
in the android app

Error in the android emulator is as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Do you have the `INTERNET` permission in the manifest?

Comment: @MikeM. Any other thing might be there

Comment: Nope. I've not done much with streaming media. I just usually forget that permission. You might try downloading the file and playing it locally to make sure VideoView doesn't just "not like it".

Comment: @MikeM. I checked in real device and videos are working but in my emulator it is not getting loaded

Answer (score 0):

- Did you set the internet permission in Manifest file?
- Are you sure its http and not https ?
- Are you running a version earlier than 3.1 ? If so, is the audio encoding through AACP?

These are some of the reasons that could give that error.

Comment: Yes i have set internet permission and yes it not https and i am using 4.3 version sdk @Jing and also i am using the H 264 compressed format videos